# React and Redux with the new auth0 SPA storing token

Tags: reactjs, redux, auth0

I'm using the new auth0-SPA to make api calls. I'm facing an issue when storing the token in redux as I am making API calls with my actions. I'm concerned about the refresh of my token where in the docs it says to use the

`await getTokenSilently()`

however I am doing this on the inital load of the context and storing that token in state, how will I know when to update the token as I can only store serialised data within state. Unlike in the docs where they are using that method directly on a fetch. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can also store your token in cookie. Your apiclient will include cookie in every API call. That also helps in dealing with browser refresh because redux will loose the token in browser refresh.

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply, its not the issue of refreshing the page, its more the fact I need to refresh the token when it expires but because Im storing a basic serialised data of the token in redux, how do I check if it needs updating